# How can I do a specific sort using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have this ArrayList in Kotlin :

```
a = ArrayList<String>()
a.add("eat")
a.add("animal")
a.add("internet")
```

And I would like to sort the elements of my ArrayList by frequency of "e" eg I would like to have a new ArrayList such as :

```
a[0] = "animal" // there is no e in animal
a[1] = "eat" // there is one e in animal
a[2] = "internet" // there is two e in internet
```

I thought to use Collections.sort(a) but like my sort is specific it won't work...

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you !

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html, https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html

Comment: Just a tip, not really related to the original question since it was already answered, but you might want to save some lines and create your arrays with `arrayOf()` function instead of doing it the "old-java-way".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing on my phone so the syntax might not be exactly correct, but something like:

```
a.sortBy { it.toCharArray().count { it == 'e' } }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this without converting each `String` to a `CharArray` first (as in the currently the accepted answer), which I don't know why you'd do:

```
a.sortBy { it.count { it == 'e' } }
```

Plus, you might want to name nested `it`s:

```
a.sortBy { word -> word.count { character -> character == 'e' } }
```